# Flutter null or emptylist

Tags: flutter, dart

it's just a small question about dart/flutter code.
I saw this code today :

```
     Future<List<String>?> getAtSignListFromKeychain() async {
    var atsignMap = await _getAtSignMap();
    if (atsignMap.isEmpty) {
      // no atsigns found in biometric storage
      // read entries from flutter keychain
      // for mobile platforms only
      if (Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS) {
        atsignMap = await checkForValuesInFlutterKeychain();
        if (atsignMap.isEmpty) {
          return null;
        }
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
    var atsigns = atsignMap.keys.toList();
    _logger.info('Retrieved atsigns $atsigns from Keychain');
    return atsigns;
  }
```

I don't understand interest of returning null with List? . Isn't better to write this code ?:

```
     Future<List<String>> getAtSignListFromKeychain() async {
    var atsignMap = await _getAtSignMap();
    if (atsignMap.isEmpty) {
      // no atsigns found in biometric storage
      // read entries from flutter keychain
      // for mobile platforms only
      if (Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS) {
        atsignMap = await checkForValuesInFlutterKeychain();
        if (atsignMap.isEmpty) {
          return atsignMap;
        }
      } else {
        return List.empty();
      }
    }
    var atsigns = atsignMap.keys.toList();
    _logger.info('Retrieved atsigns $atsigns from Keychain');
    return atsigns;
  }
```

Or I'm missing something ? Thank you !

Comment: it's the same this because i all cases you are returning an empty list returning "List.empty()" is the same as returning null because it created an empty list and for the first one to do "return atsignMap;" may cause you problems because the iniale list it's not iniatialized unless you do initiate it at the begining , it's all about good practice here

Comment: This is a opinion based question. Both ways have benefits and it also depends a lot on how this function is used in the rest of your code

Comment: Thank you @FatihaIMOUSSAINE . But If I use API getAtSignListFromKeychain so I have to check if List and null and after if List is Empty or not. But if I return an emptyList ( second approach ), I just have to check if list is empty. With Dart/Flutter, I don't understand why people return sometimes null value like this example.

Comment: it's all about how you will use if after and how you will do your check, for example : if ("return value of function"== null ) do task1 else do task2 , if you do the second example how will you check the returned value ? if you do if ("returned value of function".isEmpty) do task1 .. and the returned value is an empty list (it means null) it will generate an error which is (you can't run isEmpty on a null object) . what i want to say here you cant relay on List.isEmpty in your check in this case

Comment: @IvoBeckers, Yes for sure. But I don't understand interest of returning List<String>? if you can just check an empty list instead of check a null value and after see if it's empty or not. After this they do :  Future<String?> getAtSign() async {
    var atSignList = await getAtSignListFromKeychain();
    return atSignList == null ? atSignList as FutureOr<String?> : atSignList[0];
  }

Comment: Why they did it like that only the developer that made it knows. But in general, returning `null` can be useful in combination with the `??` operator for example for providing default values. For example `String name = getNameThatCanBeNull() ?? "defaultName";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there are always different solutions for different problems. I believe it is better to return a `null value` for some cases instead of creating an `empty list` in the memory and returning that. Either way, you have to check the `returning value`, handle errors, etc. So instead of checking if the list is empty or not, you can use just the `??` operator.

**And in some cases, the list you expect with the items in it may be empty. If you return an empty list by default in such cases, you would not know if the list that you expected is *really* empty or is there a problem.**